# How to get a roommate's dog to stop harassing girlfriends?

Tags: training, dogs

The problem: I bring over a date to the house. Roommate's dog does not leave us alone.

Well first, violence is not an option since it's usually a big turnoff to company. Separating the dog from us with a baby gate makes it cry and whine. Acknowledging the dog makes it worse, and he doesn't do it unless I have someone relatively new, thus making it hard to reproduce and ergo train.

My dog goes and finds a place to sleep when I have someone over, but from the very beginning as a puppy I taught him that he's not the center of attention and should not be around unless there's a reason. So this good behavior is just a side effect of proper training from the start.

This dog does not have that benefit of good, proper training. How can I train someone else's dog to mind his own business? Any tips? It is very aggravating since the dog in general doesn't have manners.

Comment: is your roommate home when this happens? Is so, I would just tell them to control their dog and to not let the dog bother you two.
My roommates have a dog, but they keep it in their room if they're not home, and when they are home it always stays with them.

Comment: Sounds like you need to start working on duration. Try keeping the same girlfriend for longer and longer periods of time. :-)

Comment: LLL, please rephrase your question to ask what the *roommate* should do. If the best answer is "tell the roommate" or "lock it in the bathroom", this question is more about resolving a roommate dispute and less about the **subject of pet care** and the resolution of a pet's behavioral problems. Thanks.

Comment: Lol, yes thank you all. So I will talk to my roommate about managing her dog better.

Comment: "Violence is not an option" of course it isn't! "since it's usually a big turnoff to company." wait what? you mean aside from all of the other reasons violence is wrong in general and a poor tool for training, right?

Comment: Violence to some degree is okay with dogs. This how dogs establish dominance. I sometimes just rest my legs over my dog when I'm watching TV just to remind him who's in charge. There's abuse and there's training your dog. Spanking is a tool rarely used because positive reinforcement is generally better. I love my dog very much, which why spanked him appropriately when he was younger. I can't even remember the last time I had to physically discipline him.

Comment: @LLL Dominance and alpha theory is a bunch of hokum that has been thoroughly debunked. When you're resting your legs on your dog, you're not letting him know who's in charge, you're keeping bodily contact - which your dog probably likes. Violence is never ok, not with dogs, not with people and not with other animals. Yes, punishment can be used to train dogs, but so can whipping with people, doesn't mean it's the right thing to do.